# Highcharts: Show data label at top of column graph

Tags: highcharts

I have the data that I want to display, but as a tooltip, here: http://jsfiddle.net/9rds9avr/.

```
  formatter: function () {
                        if (this.points[1].y <= this.points[0].y) {
                            var s = this.points[0].y - this.points[1].y;

                        } else {
                            var s = this.points[1].y - this.points[0].y;
                            s = '-' + s;
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
```

Note that it displays the difference between 2 series at a specific point.

I want this displayed at the top of the column, like the percentage data labels shown in this stacked chart example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/L02awbfe/7/.

How do I turn my tooltip into a datalabel? Do I need to set up a datalabel for each series?

Comment: You can enable datalabels and use [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) to customise value. Next solution is using [renderer.text](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text)

Answer (score 2):

maybe this one:

```
positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
            return { x: point.plotX + 30, y: 40 };
        },
```

[your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rds9avr/)

Comment: Thanks Ema. I actually want this value to be the datalabel (that is alwasy visible) rather than still be a tooltip and only display on hover.

Comment: According to this post : http://ahumbleopinion.com/customizing-highcharts-tooltip-visibility/  I've got following : http://jsfiddle.net/3dEJc/75/